# What is initWithCoder?

Tags: iphone

Please explain to me what is initWithCoder?

Thanks.

Comment: http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Protocols/NSCoding_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/NSCoding/initWithCoder:

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`initWithCoder:` is part of the `NSCoder` protocol, which is part of the Cocoa serialization system.  Read the [Archives and Serializations Guide for Cocoa](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/Archiving/Archiving.html).

Comment: when the initWithCoder will call or what event?

Comment: It is called when you deserialize something from a file on disk. NSCoder is a protocol for creating and reading persistent store (a file) which contains an object of a class. `initWithCoder` creates an object using data from a file.