# NSCoder, NSObject vs UIView

Tags: ios, objective-c, nscoder

When we implement `(id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)decoder` method in `NSObject` class, we need to call `[super **init**]`, but in `UIView` somehow we need to call `[super **initWithCoder:decoder**]`. Why is there such a difference?
The question is not a duplicate because it concerns protocols conformance to NSCoder in this particular case. There can well be other classes' situation similar to the one specified in the question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is initWithCoder?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1829467/what-is-initwithcoder)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should call `[super initWithCoder:decoder];` for any class that subclasses a class that already conforms to the `NSCoding` protocol.

In the case of a class that directly extends `NSObject` then of course you can't call `[super initWithCoder:decoder];` because `NSObject` doesn't conform to `NSCoder` and therefore doesn't have an `initWithCoder:` you can call from the subclass. So you must call some other `init` method.

In the case of a custom view extending `UIView`, you do call it because `UIView` conforms to `NSCoding`.